# C# Find PHP Variable from URL Code

Tags: c#, php, parsing

In C#, I want to find a PHP Variable from a URL Code.
Example: I want to find `text` out of `www.domain.com/file.php?var=text`
The main reason for this is that I want to parse the output of
`youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=`, or `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"\tempytinfo.txt"`, which is in the format of:
`?var=value&var2=value&var3=value&` ...

My efforts of trying to figure this out were sitting at Google, debugging other answers and either not working or just not what i'm looking for, and Here's my efforts so far (also with the help of the first awnser):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

        namespace ConsoleApplication2
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Paste A YouTube URL/URI to Download:");
                    string yturlstr = Console.ReadLine();
                    Uri yturl = new Uri(yturlstr);
                    Console.WriteLine("Finding ID in YouTube URL...");
                    string ytid = yturlstr.Split('?')[1];
                    ytid = ytid.Replace("v=", "");
                    Console.WriteLine("Found Watch ID.");
                    Console.WriteLine("The " + '"' + "Watch ID" + '"' + " is " + ytid);
                    Console.WriteLine("Getting Video Info...");
                    Download("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" + ytid, System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"\tempytinfo.txt");
                    Console.WriteLine("Got Info.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Reading Video Info...");
                    string viddata = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"\tempytinfo.txt");
                    Console.WriteLine("Parsing Video Info...");
                    Dictionary<string, string> videodata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    string vdt = viddata;
                    string[] vdata = vdt.Split('&');
                    foreach (char param in vdt)
                    {
                        string[] paramParts = char.ToString(param).Split('=');
                        videodata.Add(paramParts[0], paramParts[1]);
                    }
                    string uefsm = WebUtility.UrlDecode(videodata["url_encoded_fmt_stream_map"]);
                    Dictionary<string, string> videosubdata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    string[] vsdata = uefsm.Split('&');
                    foreach (char param2 in uefsm)
                    {
                        string[] paramParts2 = char.ToString(param2).Split('=');
                        videosubdata.Add(paramParts2[0], paramParts2[1]);
                    }
                    Uri downloadlink = new Uri(WebUtility.UrlDecode(videosubdata["url"]));
                    Console.WriteLine("Download Link: " + '"' + downloadlink + '"');
                    Console.ReadKey();
               }
               private static void Download(string URL, string WhereToDownload)
               {
                    var client = new WebClient();
                    Uri downloadurl = new Uri(URL);
                    client.DownloadFile(downloadurl, WhereToDownload);
                }
            }
        }
```

and my error is:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in ConsoleApplication2.exe`

`Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: post your efforts in finding answer/any code..

Comment: @utility Okay, done. Look above.

Comment: what was the output you got ?..

Comment: @utility Can you not just run it yourself? Anyway: [here](https://mega.nz/#!WkFVmY4C!AwIHM1PJj5Btd45W_ayr-tM1CHPGe41rerkfBz3kgVU)

Comment: @utility If you can't tell, it opens the raw Video Info.

Answer (score 1):

I would parse all the parameters and store them in a collection to access them easily. Suppose you have the URL in `yturl` like you do on your code, you can create the collection:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

string tmpStr = yturl.Split('?')[1];
string[] params = tmpStr.Split('&');

foreach (string param in params) 
{
    string[] paramParts = param.Split('=');
    parameters.Add(paramParts[0], paramParts[1]); 
}
```

And get, following your example, "text", with:

```
string var = parameters["var"];
// var == "text"
```

And any other parameter value by it's name:

```
string var1 = parameters["var1"];
string var2 = parameters["var2"];
```

Comment: I'm not advanced enough to change this to parse `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"\tempytinfo.txt"`, because that's what I need to parse.